# Can I use .Contains for Integer list?

Tags: c#

I have a list of integer and I want to check whether it contains several values, but it does not work and always return true in if statement.
The code is here:

```
if(IntegerList.Contains(1 | 2 |3 | 4))
{   //do something    }
```

Comment: Does your list contain the number 7? Yes is there if you get true as result of your expression

Comment: `new[] {1,2,3,4}.Any(x => IntegerList.Contains(x))`

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with asp.net or ado.net

Comment: thanks for your answers. I realize that .contain() like the way that I use works for string and if I want to use it for other type of data, I have to declare a list before it and compare integerList with that list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you're doing it checks whether the list contains `1 | 2 | 3 | 4` which is equal to `7` (bitwise OR). If your `IntegerList` does contain the value `7` then your query will indeed return `true`.

If you want to check whether `IntegerList` contains **ALL** of the items in `SearchList`, you can use the following LINQ query:

```
bool containsAll = SearchList.All(x => IntegerList.Contains(x));
```

If you want to know whether `IntegerList` contains **ANY** of the items in `SearchList`, just swap `All` with `Any`, like so:

```
bool containsAny = SearchList.Any(x => IntegerList.Contains(x));
```